# Regular Expression Matching and Replacing

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following Regular Expression that only allows a string to contain only alphabets, space, `,`, `-` and `‘`:

```
^[a-zA-Z ,\‘-]*$
```

[link to demo](http://www.regexr.com/391j0)

But I want to replace any other character other than mentioned in the regex by a space. I am intending to do this C# using `Regex.Replace()` but it is not working.

Any suggestions to this will be very helpful.

Comment: Do you want to provide a code how you do a replace?

Comment: @dotnetom I mentioned `Regex.Replace()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Negate them!

```
[^a-zA-Z ,\‘-]
```

And replace it with  space.

`^` negates the character class.

Code:

```
var str = Regex.Replace("This ) is some content", @"[^a-zA-Z ,\‘-]", " ");
```

### [**Demo**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8TOXbI)